# VMkernel not listed in vsphere machine creation wizard

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I Installed fresh ESXi 6 on my server. I connected to my server using vSphere client and add "VM Network" and "VMkernel" on vSwitch0.

I assigned valid IP address on VMkernel and want to attach it to my machine, but in machine creation wizard, I'm only able to select VM Network as NIC..

How can I attach VMKernel with assigned IP to my virtual machine? Is it right way to assign public IP address to my machine or not? If not how should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The VMKernel port and VMKernel networking layer are used by the host, not the guest. You bind the guest to the Virtual Machine Port Group of your vSwitch, not the VMKernel port of the vSwitch. You can't select the VMKernel port for your guests.

You assign an ip address in the OS of the guest just as you would for a physical machine running the same OS.